# Remove NA in front of one specific string but leave in front of another specific string, by group

Tags: r, zoo

I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:4, each = 4), 
  status = c(
    NA, "a", "c", "a", 
    NA, "b", "c", "c",
    NA, NA, "a", "c",
    NA, NA, "b", "b"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

For each group (id), I aim to remove the rows with one or multiple leading NA in front of an "a" (in the column "status") but not in front of a "b".

The final data frame should look like this:

```
structure(list(
  id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
  status = c("a", "c", "a", NA, "b", "c", "c", "a", "c", NA, NA, "b", "b")), 
  .Names = c("id", "status"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I do that?

Edit: alternatively, how would I do it to preserve other variables in the data frame such as the variable otherVar in the following example:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
   id = rep(1:4, each = 4), 
   status = c(
    NA, "a", "c", "a", 
    NA, "b", "c", "c",
    NA, NA, "a", "c",
    NA, NA, "b", "b"),
  otherVar = letters[1:16],
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'id', `summarise` the 'status' by `paste`ing the elements together, then use `gsub` to remove the `NA` before the 'a' and convert it to 'long' format with `separate_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
 group_by(id) %>%
 summarise(status = gsub("(NA, ){1,}(?=a)", "", toString(status), 
       perl = TRUE)) %>% 
 separate_rows(status, convert = TRUE) 
# A tibble: 13 x 2
#      id status
#   <int> <chr> 
# 1     1 a     
# 2     1 c     
# 3     1 a     
# 4     2 NA    
# 5     2 b     
# 6     2 c     
# 7     2 c     
# 8     3 a     
# 9     3 c     
#10     4 NA    
#11     4 NA    
#12     4 b     
#13     4 b
```

---

Or using `data.table` with the same methodology

```
library(data.table)
out1 <- setDT(df)[, strsplit(gsub("(NA, ){1,}(?=a)", "", 
            toString(status), perl = TRUE), ", "), id]
setnames(out1, 'V1', "status")[]
#    id status
# 1:  1      a
# 2:  1      c
# 3:  1      a
# 4:  2     NA
# 5:  2      b
# 6:  2      c
# 7:  2      c
# 8:  3      a
# 9:  3      c
#10:  4     NA
#11:  4     NA
#12:  4      b
#13:  4      b
```

#### Update

For the updated dataset 'df2'

```
i1 <- setDT(df2)[, .I[seq(which(c(diff((status %in% "a") + 
              rleid(is.na(status))) > 1), FALSE))]  , id]$V1
df2[-i1]
#     id status otherVar
# 1:  1      a        b
# 2:  1      c        c
# 3:  1      a        d
# 4:  2     NA        e
# 5:  2      b        f
# 6:  2      c        g
# 7:  2      c        h
# 8:  3      a        k
# 9:  3      c        l
#10:  4     NA        m
#11:  4     NA        n
#12:  4      b        o
#13:  4      b        p
```

Comment: @Roccer Thanks, I didn't notice it.  Updated the code

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works like charm. However, I accept the solution of Wen as it seems simpler to me.

Comment: @RonakShah Where exactly is not matching

Comment: @RonakShah  Thanks for the comment, that made me look into the type of NA.  I need to change it

Comment: For my original dataset your first option worked best.

Comment: dplyr and tidyr seems like over kill here :-)

Comment: @Wen Yeah, you are right.  I was first on a `filter` way, thought that will be the correct way, but then I have to make some "adjustments" to make it work :=)

Comment: @akrun good to know regex can be used in this situation :-) learn new things thanks man

Comment: @Wen The regex was based on the OP's example.  There could be some edge cases though

Comment: @akrun, I just figured out this removes all other columns of my dataset except for the "id" and "status". Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Roccer Could you please update your example.  Thanks

Comment: @akrun I did by adding a column with letters.

Comment: @Roccer I added a data.table solution.  It is a bit tricky to change the original solution with `gsub`.

Comment: @akrun Works perfectly! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

From `zoo` with `na.locf` and `is.na`, notice it assuming you data is ordered.

```
df[!(na.locf(df$status,fromLast = T)=='a'&is.na(df$status)),]
   id status
2   1      a
3   1      c
4   1      a
5   2   <NA>
6   2      b
7   2      c
8   2      c
11  3      a
12  3      c
13  4   <NA>
14  4   <NA>
15  4      b
16  4      b
```

Comment: I get the warning "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" when applying that code to my original dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution and a not as pretty `base` translation :

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  filter(status[!is.na(status)][1]!="a" | !is.na(status))

# # A tibble: 13 x 2
# # Groups:   id [4]
#       id status
#    <int>  <chr>
#  1     1      a
#  2     1      c
#  3     1      a
#  4     2   <NA>
#  5     2      b
#  6     2      c
#  7     2      c
#  8     3      a
#  9     3      c
# 10     4   <NA>
# 11     4   <NA>
# 12     4      b
# 13     4      b
```

**base**

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(split(df,df$id),
               function(x) x[x$status[!is.na(x$status)][1]!="a" | !is.na(x$status),]))

#      id status
# 1.2   1      a
# 1.3   1      c
# 1.4   1      a
# 2.5   2   <NA>
# 2.6   2      b
# 2.7   2      c
# 2.8   2      c
# 3.11  3      a
# 3.12  3      c
# 4.13  4   <NA>
# 4.14  4   <NA>
# 4.15  4      b
# 4.16  4      b
```

**note**

Will fail if not all `NAs` are leading because will remove all `NAs` from groups starting with `"a"` as a first non `NA` value.